# Highcharter Map for categories

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I am trying to create a Highchart Map of Europe with R for categories instead of numbers.

Lets say I have the dataset below and I want that the Map shows a color for each category. Categories are: "Red", "Blue", "Green".

```
library(highcharter)
mapData <- data_frame(country = c("PT", "FR", "IT", "DE"), 
value = c("Red","Blue","Green","Red"))
```

Then I need the map to show the categories:

```
hcmap(map = 'custom/europe', data = mapData,
  joinBy = c("iso-a2","country"), value = "value")
```

The problem is that the result gives me black for each country in my `data frame`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion for a possible solution:

```
mapData <- tibble(country = c("PT", "FR", "IT", "DE"),  
                  value = c(1, 2, 3, 1))

hcmap(map = 'custom/europe', data = as.data.frame(mapData),
  joinBy = c("iso-a2","country"), value = "value") %>%
  hc_colorAxis(dataClassColor="category", 
     dataClasses = list(list(from=1, to=1, color="red", name="PT-DE"),
                        list(from=2, to=2, color="blue", name="FR"),
                        list(from=3, to=3, color="green", name="IT")))
```

[image]